# API call throws sslhandshakeexception despite taking recommended steps

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc, ssl

I have a simple Spring mvc application running on Windows 8.1 that calls one [iexapis](https://iexcloud.io/cloud-login) endpoint and logs output. For security, the call uses my token provided by iexapis that communicates with the iexapis server and grants me access to the endpoint data. It worked fine up until (according to iexapis) "a root SSL authority made changes that has affected some of our customers". I now get this exception:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

They recommended I clear my ssl & dns caches. So, I did the following:

- chrome settings -> searched for 'proxy'-> *Open your computer's proxy settings* -> *Content* tab -> *Clear SSL State* -> *OK* -> restarted chrome
- in  windows command prompt, I ran ipconfig /flushdns.

When that didn't help, they recommended I "fully clear out my Java cache to keep making calls from a Java environment". So, I went to *Control Panel -> Programs -> Java -> Settings -> Delete Files -> Check all boxes (Trace and log files, Cached applications and applets, installed applications and applets) -> OK -> OK -> OK*.

Despite all this, I'm still getting the above exception. So even though I'm still talking to the iexapis techies, and even though I can think of **nothing** in my code that could be causing this exception, can someone please help me confirm this (pasted below)?

If not a problem with the code...other suggestions for addressing the exception?

Application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

An Interface

```
public interface ControllerAssist {
    String sendGet(String url);
    String callApi() throws Exception;
}
```

Interface Implementation

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ControllerAssistImpl implements ControllerAssist {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ControllerAssistImpl.class.getName());

    // Make http connection to API URL, convert stream to String data
    public String sendGet(String url) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            // Create url
            URL obj = new URL(url);

            // Create connection
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // Response code
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            // Log
            log.log(Level.INFO, "sendGet() responseCode: ", responseCode);

            StringBuffer response;

            // BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br
                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            // Hold input
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            // Loop
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            // Close
            br.close();

            // Assign result
            result = response.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "sendGet() - MalformedURLException: ",ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "sendGet() - IOException: ", ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Call API
    public String callApi() throws Exception {

        // URL string
        String stringURL = 
            "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/AA/earnings/1?token="
                + "pk_my_token";

        // Log
        log.log(Level.INFO, "callApi - stringUrl: {0}", new Object[]{stringURL});

        // Grab api response
        return sendGet(stringURL);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    ControllerAssist controllerAssist;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() throws Exception {
        controllerAssist.callApi();
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception simply means that your JVM does not accept the certificate of the HTTPS endpoint. You should check that certificate, and either not call the endpoint, or add that certificate (or better, the root certificate) to the truststore - i.e. the file `cacerts`.

Comment: Which Java version and type (Sun/Oracle, other OpenJDK like Adopt Coretto or Zulu, IBM), and if OpenJDK OS/platform? That site uses one of the Comodo/Sectigo CAs affected by the May 30 expiration of the old AddTrust root, but its direct root 'comodorsaca' has been in _Oracle_ Java since 8u51 in 2015. (And all 3 of their recommendations are irrelevant to the problem, and thus silly.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Oracle jdk1.8.0_45. Hm, so update to 8u51?

Comment: Actually, just update.

Comment: Updated to 1.8.0_251 and now all is well. Thanks @dave_thompson_085. Please add your answer as the answer and I'll choose it. If not, I'll post it as the answer later today.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Thanks for the suggestion. Yours was my back up option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for direction that led to the answer. I updated to jdk 1.8.0_251 and everything works fine.